# How to get time diff between 2 times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 columns with data type Time.

**Ex:**

```
08:00:00 - 12:00:00 = 4
08:30:00 - 23:00:00 = 15.5
20:00:00 - 00:00:00 = 4
22:00:00 - 06:00:00 = 8
```

Comment: check `DateDiff` function

Comment: DATEDIFF result is negative when calucate this  22:00:00 - 06:00:00

Comment: @AthitUpakan can You add full days to this dates or it has to stay with hours only?

Comment: So handle the negative value. DATEDIFF is still your best option.

Comment: Because you have mentioned only times here. Is the second column always reprents next day?. In otherwords Will second column value is always greater than 1st column (if we consider along with date)? How do you differenciate  22:00:00 - 23:00:00 = 1hr or 22:00:00 - 23:00:00 = 25hrs( 23, 24, 1, 2...23)

Comment: How do you know those times are belonged to which dates?

Comment: use 'DateDiff'  to get time difference and then use 'ABS' function to get output as positive always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @time1 TIME ='22:00:00'
DECLARE @time2 TIME ='06:00:00'

SELECT CEILING(CAST(Diff as decimal)/(60 * 60)) FROM (SELECT  
CASE WHEN CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@time1,@time2) AS INT) > 0 THEN  CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@time1,@time2) AS INT)
ELSE (ABS(CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,CAST('23:59:59' AS TIME),@time1) AS INT)) + ABS(CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@time2,CAST('00:00:00' as TIME)) AS INT)))
END AS Diff) AS A
```

**UPDATE**

The above rounds the result to next Hour using ceiling function, for hours in fractional part use below snippet

```
DECLARE @time1 TIME ='023:30:00'
DECLARE @time2 TIME ='06:00:00'

SELECT Round(CAST(Diff as decimal)/(60 * 60),2) FROM (SELECT  
CASE WHEN CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@time1,@time2) AS INT) > 0 THEN  CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@time1,@time2) AS INT)
ELSE (ABS(CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,CAST('23:59:59' AS TIME),@time1) AS INT)) + ABS(CAST(DATEDIFF(SECOND,@time2,CAST('00:00:00' as TIME)) AS INT)))
END AS Diff) AS A
```

Comment: @AthitUpakan , The result will fail in fractional hour `08:30:00 - 23:00:00 = 15.5`, check the updated snippet

Answer (score 3):

All of the answers suggesting to use `ABS` seem to be mis-thinking the situation here. If the result is negative then that means that the times crossed a date boundary, and the simple remedy there is to add 24 hours to the result to get the correct value.

Since you only have times, we have to assume that any given pair of times represent a period of less than 24 hours (otherwise, there's no means of distinguishing a pair of times that represent a 2 hour interval from a pair of times that represent a 26 hour interval).

So, what we can do is to always add 24 hours to the result and then take the result modulo 24 hours.

Here's the calculation in minutes:

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(minute,FirstValue,SecondValue) + (24*60)) % (24*60)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATEDIFF`

**Query**

```
declare @t1 as time = '08:30:00';
declare @t2 as time = '23:00:00';

select abs(cast((datediff(minute, @t1, @t2)) as float) / 60);
```

**Result**

```
14.5
```

And you can change the variables, `@t1` and `@t2` to your column names.

**Update**

You can use a `CASE` expression to check when the first time is greater that second time column value. If it is greater then the second time column should be in the next day.

**Query**

```
select
case when t1 > t2 then 
cast(
    datediff(
        minute,
        cast(
            cast(
                getdate() as date
            )
            as varchar(50)
        )
        + ' ' +
        cast(
            cast(
                left(t1, charindex('.', t1, 1) - 1)
                as varchar(50)
            )
            as datetime
        ), 
        cast(
            cast(
                getdate() + 1 as date
            )
            as varchar(50)
        )
        + ' ' +
        cast(
            cast(
                left(t2, charindex('.', t1, 1) - 1)
                as varchar(50)
            )
            as datetime
        )
    )
    as float
) / 60
else cast((datediff(minute, t1, t2)) as float) / 60 end
from [your_table_name];
```

**[Find demo here](http://rextester.com/QTHQX67782)**

Comment: if @t2 = '06:00:00' in next day
result is negative

Comment: @AthitUpakan : Use `ABS` function for that. Updated the answer.

Comment: @AthitUpakan : Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @start time;
DECLARE @end time;
DECLARE @null time;

SET @start = '09:06:00';
SET @end = '21:27:00';
SET @null = '00:00:00';

SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, - DATEDIFF(SECOND, @end, @start), @null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) Function

as next

```
select datediff(hour,'08:00:00','12:00:00')
```

Result:-

```
4
```

**UPDATE**

for getting absolute (Positive) value use [ABS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx) function as next

```
select abs(datediff(hour,'22:00:00','06:00:00'))
```

Result:-

```
16
```

**UPDATE2:-**

```
declare 
        @StartTime datetime = '22:00:00',
        @EndTime datetime = '06:00:00'


if (datepart(hour,@StartTime) >= 12)
set @StartTime = dateadd(day,-1,@StartTime)

select abs(datediff(hour,@StartTime,@EndTime))
```

Result:-

```
8
```

Comment: thanks, i dont need negative result in 22:00:00 - 06:00:00

Comment: @AthitUpakan check the answer after updating, is it what you are looking for ?

Comment: thank for update, i need result is 8 hours not 16 hours.

Comment: You mean 4 not 8 ??

Comment: 22:00:00 - 06:00:00
->23, 24, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 => 8 hours

Comment: @AthitUpakan and what about start time = `7:00:00` and End time = `6:00:00`, The result should be 1 or 23 ??

Comment: @AthitUpakan check the answer after second Updating.

Comment: thanks, it wrong result in normal case (04:00:00-06:00:00).

Comment: @AthitUpakan , and what about now ?